# Get the outside points from an array and draw around them to create the biggest shape

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, drawing, coordinates

Okay guys, so what I have is a bunch of smaller shapes (all squares with 4 points top, right, bottom and left, each that has an x and y). I've extracted an array of all the points from all the squares which looks like:

[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], ... etc]

There could be hundreds of squares all bunched together to make any kind of shape.

What I want to know is:

How would I extract all of the points that lie around the outside perimeter of all of the points and then loop through them so that I can draw a path around the outside of those points to create an outline shape of all the squares as a cluster.

I am using javascript and a canvas to draw my shape.

Cheers.

Comment: Would you make a small jsfiddle with some dummy data? so that I can try it around... @Daniel

Comment: By saying... "all squares with 4 points top, right, bottom and left, each that has an x and y" do you mean top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right coordinates.? It would be much logical if you had an array of individual arrays per each square's 4 corner points. But seems interesting. I will think about this.

Comment: Well thinking about it the fact they are the coordinates of the points of squares doesnt matter, I just have a bunch of points that I want to draw an outline around. I will try and do a fiddle.

Comment: OK got it.. but do these coordinates come in a sorted order of how they are connected..? If not then it might become an unsolvable or a multiple solution problem since you may connect arbitrary points in a number of ways so that you can still end up with a different closed shape with no lines crossing each other. That's why it's best if the 4 points of each square stays together in an individual array. It's important to know these before you start, in order not to end up in a swamp.

Comment: To solve this you need to define the rules that define if any two boxes are connected. Then group all connected boxes. Start at he top most left most and iterate via moving clockwise to the next box. You can not move to a box if you need to cross a connection.  When you return to the start you have bounded all members of the group. Without the connection rule, which you have not given (only hinted could be spatial) the problem is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

**An outline of a brute force method for getting an outside path (not optimized!)**

[image]

1. Create line segments from the sides of all of your rectangles and put all the segments in an array. The line segment objects might be shaped like this: `{id:1,x0:,y0:,x1:,y1:}`

   - red line segments:  [#1,#6], [#6,#7], [#7,#8], [#8,#1]
   - blue line segments: [#3,#4], [#4,#10], [#10,#9], [#9,#3]
2. Loop through the array and find the segment with the leftmost x0. If there are more than one segments with the leftmost x0, then, from that subset, choose the segment that has the topmost y0. *(This is marker#1 in the illustration)*
3. Call this the "source segment" *(marker#1 to marker#6 on the illustration)*.
4. Loop through the array and find a segment (if any) that intersects the source segment. Don't test the source segment against itself ;-). You can use the `line-line intersection` algorithm below to find an intersection with the source line. The line-line intersection algorithm returns intersecting point (if any) of 2 line segments. *(marker#2 on the illustration)*
5. Calculate the distance between the source segment's x0,y0 and the intersection's x,y point. You can calculate the distance with the distance formula *(distance between marker#1 & marker#2 on the illustration)*:

   ```
   var dx = intersection.x - source.x0;
   var dy = intersection.y - source.y0;
   var distance=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
   ```
6. Do steps #4-#5 for every segment versus the source segment and find the segment that intersects the source segment soonest (==distance is the smallest). *(This intersecting segment is marker#9 to marker#3 on the illustration)*
7. If there is no intersecting line, then use the source line's x1,y1 and call that x1,y1 the "intersection point". *A line segment without intersections is  between marker#3 and marker#4 on the illustration.*
8. At the intersection point you must determine whether to turn towards the intersecting segment's x0,y0 or towards it's x1,y1. Go "clockwise" by always going to the intersecting segment's x1,y1.
9. This new line segment between the intersection x,y point and the intersecting line's x0,y0 (or x1,y1) is now the new "source segment". *This new source segment is marker#2 to marker#3 on the illustration*

   - If the end x,y of the new source is back to the same original x,y that you found in step#2, then you have solved the perimeter. Congratulations! *This occurs when you travel from marker#8 to marker#1 on the illustration*
   - If not, go back to step#3 using this new source segment.

Note: This method will *only find attached (touching) rects* -- any disconnected rect will not be discovered. One additional task you might want to do is see if any rect is disconnected and decide how you want to treat that disconnected rect. *The green rect on the illustration is disconnected.*

**This algorithm will find the intersection point (if any) of 2 line segments:**

```
// Get interseting point of 2 line segments (if any)
// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {

    var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        

    // Test if Coincident
    // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
    //    then the two lines are coincident.    
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}

    // Test if Parallel 
    // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
    //     then the two lines are parallel. 
    if (denominator == 0) return null;

    // If the intersection of line segments is required 
    // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
    // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
    // line segment contains the intersection point. 
    // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
    // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;

    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)

    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}

    return({
        x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
        y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative that analyzes the pixels to fetch the perimeter of the assembly. It uses the Marching Squares algorithm to fetch that perimeter. Stackoverflow's K3N has done a nice [Marching Squares script](https://github.com/epistemex/msqr) that also allows for simplification of the resulting point-set.

Then snap each of the perimeter points to known rectangle vertices or known rectangle intersections.

[image]

Here is example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var r1={x:20,y:60,w:100,h:40,color:'red',id:0}
var r2={x:50,y:20,w:40,h:60,color:'blue',id:1}
var r3={x:100,y:80,w:100,h:60,color:'green',id:2}
var r4={x:160,y:80,w:70,h:60,color:'purple',id:3}
var rects=[r1,r2,r3,r4];
var rpts=[];

ctx.translate(0.50,0.50);
var nextId=0;
for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var r=rects[i];
    var x=r.x;
    var y=r.y;
    var w=r.w;
    var h=r.h;
    ctx.strokeStyle=r.color;
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
    rpts.push({x:x,y:y},{x:x+w,y:y},{x:x+w,y:y+h},{x:x,y:y+h});
}

function multiRectVertices(rects){
    var pts=[];
    var segs=[];

    // rectangle vertices
    for(var r=0;r<rects.length;r++){
        var rect=rects[r];
        var x=rect.x;
        var y=rect.y;
        var w=rect.w;
        var h=rect.h;
        pts.push([x,y]);
        pts.push([x+w,y]);
        pts.push([x+w,y+h]);
        pts.push([x,y+h]);
        segs.push({x0:x,   y0:y,   x1:x+w, y1:y});
        segs.push({x0:x+w, y0:y,   x1:x+w, y1:y+h});
        segs.push({x0:x+w, y0:y+h, x1:x,   y1:y+h});
        segs.push({x0:x,   y0:y+h, x1:x,   y1:y});
    }

    // intersection points
    for(var s=0;s<segs.length;s++){
        line0=segs[s];
        for(var i=s+1;i<segs.length;i++){
            var intersection=line2lineIntersection(line0,segs[i]);
            if(intersection){ pts.push([intersection.x,intersection.y]);}
        }
    }

    //
    return(pts);
}

// get rect vertices and intersections
var rectPts=multiRectVertices(rects);

// get simplified perimeter based on pixels
// Attribution: K3N on Stackoverflow, epistemex on GitHub: 
// https://github.com/epistemex/msqr 
var msPts=MSQR(ctx,{alpha:200,tolerance:1.1})[0];

alignMSPts(msPts,rectPts);

function alignMSPts(msPts,rectPts){
    var pt,rpt,px,py,rx,ry,dx,dy,minDist,dist;
    for(var i=0;i<msPts.length;i++){
        minDist=1000000*100000;
        pt=msPts[i];
        px=pt.x;
        py=pt.y;
        for(var j=0;j<rectPts.length;j++){
            rpt=rectPts[i];
            rx=rpt.x;
            ry=rpt.y;
            dx=px-rx;
            dy=py-ry;
            dist=dx*dx+dy*dy;
            if(dist<minDist){
                minDist=dist;
                msPts[i]={x:rx,y:ry};
            }
        }
    }
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(msPts[0].x,msPts[0].y);
for(var i=1;i<msPts.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(msPts[i].x,msPts[i].y);
}
ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();


ctx.fillStyle='gold';
for(var i=0;i<msPts.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(msPts[i].x,msPts[i].y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
}


// Get interseting point of 2 line segments (if any)
// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
// Segment #1: [x0,y0] to [x1,y1], Segment#2: [x2,y2] to [x3,y3]
function line2lineIntersection(line0,line1){
    var x0=line0.x0;
    var y0=line0.y0;
    var x1=line0.x1;
    var y1=line0.y1;
    var x2=line1.x0;
    var y2=line1.y0;
    var x3=line1.x1;
    var y3=line1.y1;
    var unknownA = (x3-x2) * (y0-y2) - (y3-y2) * (x0-x2);
    var unknownB = (x1-x0) * (y0-y2) - (y1-y0) * (x0-x2);
    var denominator  = (y3-y2) * (x1-x0) - (x3-x2) * (y1-y0);        
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}
    if (denominator == 0) return null;
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;
    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)
    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}
    return({
        x: x0 + unknownA * (x1-x0),
        y: y0 + unknownA * (y1-y0)
    });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/epistemex/msqr/master/msqr.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```